# How to bring a server online and link it to parse.com?

Tags: parse-platform

I have a server of my own running locally on my wifi, on 0.0.0.0:5000.

I have built an app with the parse.com backend, and I want to link this server to Cloud Code, so I can call functions on it.

I am completely lost and don't know where to start to bring my server online with only Parse being able to access it and use its API.

Or am I better off renting a VPS and connecting to that?

Comment: Cloud code can access publicly visible servers only, through the Parse.Cloud.httpRequest method.

Comment: so how would i make my server publicly visible? I can add on authentication later.

Comment: Would be best to use a VPS (digitalocean maybe?).. hosting on your home internet connection is a can of worms (and has nothing to do with parse, etc) involving changes to your router/firewall and may be blocked by your ISP.

Comment: Thanks, I'll go the VPS route.